# ReactJS Starter - Unexpected tokens JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I just started looking into ReactJS (not really experienced with any of the javascript libraries or frameworks, except for jQuery).

I followed the following pages from the ReactJS website (https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html and https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html), but I keep getting the same error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I don't really know what causes this, when I use this code in CodePen, it works just fine. Do I need to add a couple of other JS files in my index?

Current files:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id="root"></div>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Thank you all in advance!

PS: when I add import React and import ReactDOM, I get an Unexpected identifier error.

Comment: JSX is not proper JavaScript, but is [compiled down to `React.createElement` calls](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwCwjAfAEgpgNnA9gGgAQHdECc4BMCEwA9OBEA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=), so you must compile it or use [Babel in the browser for testing purposes](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone).

Comment: Did you also follow the steps listed here: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-jsx-to-a-project ? JSX isn't actually valid Javascript in any version of the spec, you need a transpiler (like Babel) to convert it to valid JS

Comment: @RobinZigmond I didn't know that, I will be looking into that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

the main problem is that your missing the React.createElement() so your `<h1>Hello, world!</h1>` is interpreted as plain text.

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement('h1', null, 'Hello World'),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Change your code to this and it should work.

:)

Comment: Thanks! The code works indeed. So from what I've read, I need to use Babel if I want to use JSX. That I didn't know, so I will be looking into that :)